# Postgresql: How to access camelcased keys from Record structured in function triggers

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'm using postgres 9.5, and defining a trigger to be run when a row is added to a table, something in the line of:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addedTrigger AFTER INSERT ON ships 
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE added();
```

My `added` function is written in plpgsql, and its purpose is to fetch some data, assemble it into a certain format, and send over pg_notify to a channel. This is something resembling the body:

```
$$
BEGIN
PERFORM pg_notify('events', json_build_object('type', 'ADDED', 'userId', NEW.userId)::text);
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
```

However, when the trigger runs, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "userid"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT NEW.userId"
PL/pgSQL function added() line 5 at RAISE
```

Somehow the plpgsql function is downcasing my key annotation internally, and I'm not sure exactly how to proper use this, as all the examples I see in the wild are with non-primary-or-foreign-key attributes, and all of them are downcased.

Comment: error from `friendregistered()`, but you have `added()` in trigger - smth you dont tell us?..

Comment: apologies, got lost in the whole renaming my functions :)

Comment: there is mixed case in `NEW.userId` - if you have it indeed, then change to `NEW."userId"`

Comment: Nice, fixed! Can I ask why this happens? And also, could you post this as an answer, so I can give you proper credit?

Comment: sure. posted with links and explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ERROR:  record "new" has no field "userid"

Is indeed a right error - there is no column **"userid"** (see the name is different in error then in your code). If you use a mixed case (or start identifier with number or special character or use any other not common name) you have to double quote the identifier, so `NEW."userId"` should work for you.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html

> SQL is case insensitive about key words and identifiers, except when
>   identifiers are double-quoted to preserve the case